# Data too long for column 'Subscribe_Specialty' at row 1 - Mysql error

Tags: mysql, database

**Here is the insert statement -**

```
INSERT INTO `Newsletter_Subscriber_Uploaded_Data`(`File_Id`, `First_Name`, `Last_Name`, `Email`,`Country`,`Country_Id`,`Subscribe_Specialty`,Is_Valid, `Subscription_Id`, `User_Id`, `Created_Date`) 
VALUES (2, 'Adolphus','Bonar', 'a.bonar@endocrinology.org', 'United States','2', 'General Practice/Family Medicine', 1 ,20, '89',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

For column `Subscribe_Specialty`, the value I'm trying to insert is `'General Practice/Family Medicine'` which has only 32 characters, but still it is giving me the above error.
Please help me guys, as this is a production error.

More Information:

- Collation : utf8
- Storage Engine : InnoDB

**Below is the Table structure -**

```
CREATE TABLE `Newsletter_Subscriber_Uploaded_Data` ( 
    `File_Id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
    `Row_Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `First_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    `Last_Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
    `Email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `Country` varchar(20) NOT NULL, 
    `Country_Id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `Subscribe_Specialty` varchar(100) NOT NULL, 
    `Is_Valid` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0', 
    `Subscription_Id` int(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', 
    `Duplicate` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0', 
    `Subscriber` tinyint(4) DEFAULT '0', 
    `Created_Date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    `User_Id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Panel user id', 
    PRIMARY KEY (`Row_Id`), 
    KEY `File_Id` (`File_Id`) 
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=21511 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: set text type to 'Subscribe_Specialty'

Comment: Can you show `SHOW CREATE TABLE Newsletter_Subscriber_Uploaded_Data`?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting for how to format code in posts so it's readable.

Comment: What is type for the same column.

Comment: It's a varchar (100)  @ jyoti mishra

Comment: changing to text data type won't be a right solution for this - @ pAsh

Comment: I have added the table structure.please go through it @Barmar

Comment: @kiran : just tried with your two querries, create database and insert into. everything is working fine here. i can insert the same data. are you still facing the problem?

Comment: See https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18908 the comments there suggest executing a `set names utf8;` query as the solution.

Comment: @jyoti mishra : yes i'm still facing that issue.